# Скругление рамки ProgressBar | JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx

Подскажите как можно скруглить рамку, показывающую размеры шкалы прогресса. Как я понял, это stroke, однако как изменить, я не знаю. Скриншот рамки, которую хочу скруглить, ниже. [image]

Comment: Если там css, то border-radius

Comment: border-radius от чего именно? Там тип несколько селекторов есть

Comment: Так кода нет, и ответы соответственные. А так сам селектор прогресса